# Multiple views to nested state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router and I try to create several views inside one of my nested states. 
In my logic, all of the views should be visible whenever the parent state is active.

I have read the wiki page on [multiple named views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views) multiple times, but could not get anything working yet. 
My state template would show up, but my views never do.

[**Here is a working plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/xVtb34aFokcN2aZohgIa) 
(You have to click on "Followers" in the navbar for the view to show up. Haven't figured why yet).

Important parts are the config

```
app.config([
    '$stateProvider', 
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
        $stateProvider
        .state('dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard', 
            templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
            controller: 'DashboardCtrl',
            authenticate: true
        }).state('dashboard.followers', {
            url: '/followers', 
            templateUrl: 'dashboard.followers.html',
            controller: 'DFollowersCtrl',                
            authenticate: true 
        }).state('dashboard.followers.add', {
            views: {
                'add': {
                    templateUrl: 'dashboard.followers.add.html',
                    controller: 'DFollowersAddCtrl',
                    authenticate: true
                }
            },
        });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('dashboard');
    }
]);
```

The main dashboard template (level 2, using a generic ui-view)

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
    <div class="flash-area">
        <flash-message duration="2000" show-close="true"></flash-message>
    </div>
    <ui-view></ui-view>
</div>
```

and the dashobard.followers specific level 3 view, that has a specific name

```
<div>

    <h1 class="page-header">Followers</h1>

    <div ui-view="add"></div>

</div>
```

The trick is coming from, I think, a combination of :

- I want to use level 3 nesting
- Level 2 uses a generic ui-view, because it may contains my dashboard or something else.
- Level 3 contains specific views, as it is where I want to use "views" and not "states" (as far as I understood, at least).

The final aim is to have more than one view in my template, but for now I reduced the attempts to only show the 'add' view.

I have seen several similar questions on SO already, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36293741/angular-ui-router-multiple-named-views-and-nested-states) or [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27861286/angular-ui-router-nested-views-issue) but so far my attempts have not been fruitful.

- I can access my "add" view directly if I reach its URL (when I try setting one)
- But the dashboard.followers state does not get populated by the views.

Comment: /dashboard/followers/followers -> dashboard.followers.add?

Comment: If you mean that I can access the view directly via the url, yes you are right. However the idea is to make it load in my followers view directly ( 
/dashboard/followers).

Comment: No, what I was trying to show you is that /dashboard/followers/followers it's an ugly path, what about  /dashboard/followers/add?. Anyway, try crafting a codepen, cheers.

Comment: Hey, you are right. It actually is what I have in my last commit. It must be a remnant of a bad test. Sorry for that. Will open a codepen during lunch :).

Comment: @jlengrand give me some feedback on my answer, if it's not working let me know

Comment: Thanks guys. I created 2 plunkers with some simplifications for you to see. I don't think the solution from Zhiliang solved my issue yet. Or at least I did not get it to work. https://plnkr.co/edit/mw2QcGcduN6ki9acLJww

Comment: so actually you want your follower state to show up without click?

Comment: No, What I want is the dashboard.followers.add to be inserted into the followers state. In the current plunker, when the dashboardfollowers state is selected, the ui-view that is named "add" stays empty even though the configuration requests for dashboard.followers.add to be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are several mistakes here you made:

1. if you want the url of `dashboard.followers` state and `dashboard.followers.add` state to be same, the child state `dashboard.followers.add` does not need the `url` option
2. probably can be a mistake(I am not sure because no code is provided), if you don't use the 

   `views: { ... }`
    
   named views, but just directly use 
   `url: '/followers', 
   templateUrl: '/partials/dashboard.followers.html'`

   angular just assume you want to insert the template in an unnamed `<div ui-view></div>` in the parents state's template not the root template. for example, in my example code, for state `dashboard.followers`, since it is a child state of `dashboard`, if I want to insert the template in root html template, I have to use

   `views: {
     '@': {
       template: '<div><h1 class="page-header">Followers</h1><a ui-sref="dashboard.followers.add">add</a><div ui-view="add"></div></div>'
     }
   }`

```js
/* myApp module */
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
  .config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider
      .state('landing', {
        url: '/',
        template: '<p>landing</p><a ui-sref="dashboard">dashboard</a>'
      })
      .state('dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        template: '<p>landing</p><a ui-sref="dashboard.followers">followers</a>'
      })
      .state('dashboard.followers', {
        url: '/followers',
        views: {
          '@': {
            template: '<div><h1 class="page-header">Followers</h1><a ui-sref="dashboard.followers.add">add</a><div ui-view="add"></div></div>'
          }
        }
      })
      .state('dashboard.followers.add', {
        views: {
          'add': {
            template: '<p>followers</p>'
          }
        }
      });
  }])
  .controller('MyAppCtrl', function($scope, $state /*, $stateParams*/ ) {
    $state.go("landing");
  });
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyAppCtrl">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  

  <div ui-view></div>

</body>
```

## update

I made two plunkers to fit two different situation:

1. if you want to dynamically load `add` state to `ui-view="add"` by a
   link, check
   [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/bIgNCJ50KL7clVOViO7w?p=preview) out.
2. if you just want a sub template to be loaded always on `dashboard.followers` state, simply remove `add` states, and use `views: {...}` to load the `add` template in. here is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/HEVXb1PSeXi0cZ6bi4vc?p=preview).

Comment: @jlengrand this seems to work, give us some feedback and I'll add my own answer if this one is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I try your snippet but unfortunately if I do that it hides my left bar. You can see the result in this plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/mw2QcGcduN6ki9acLJww (click on followers)

Comment: I suggest you to read this [document](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views), it is really helpful for you to understand how the nested named view works. I have updated my answer for you :)

Comment: Thanks Zhiliang. The page you are linking too is the one I link in the description of the issue already :). That is how I got to the current configuration. In your plunker. when the dashboard.followers state is selected, the dashboard.followers.add does not get loaded in the ui-view="add". That is my current issue.

Comment: sorry actually changed it based on the old one, on my pc it's the new version, i m not familiar with plunker, just one thing to check, you wanna load add states to the ui-view="add" by default without click?(basically u just wanna loaded the template in), or u wanna a link to click then switch to state `add` then load the template.

Comment: i have added the new answers @jlengrand

Comment: The second version is exactly what I wanted, thanks a lot! I had not tried to put all my views in the same state, but it sounds logical now that you showed it :).